# Creating a search filter with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I'm stuck on this,

```
    <input type="text" name="search">
    <select>
    <option value="Name">Name</option>
    <option value="Address">Address</option>
    <option value="company_address">company_address</option>
    <option value="contact_number">contact_number</option>
    </select>
<input type="submit">

<?php
include "connect.php";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM propertydetail";
x
?>
```

My question is, How can I use PHP to select a row from my database with filled information, by querying lets say option "name" out of one of my options.
I need it to echo out all information from that name, even if it's given more than once in the table of my database.

```
$output = NULL;
$output .= '<div>'. $name . $address .'</div>';

echo $output;
```

I can format this better using a table within my php, 
So basically what I'm asking is, How would I select 
"Row from database"

by querying just a single name. Thanks in advance. I'm just a beginner, so don't judge me too hard.

Comment: Are you asking how to use the `WHERE` keyword in SQL?

Comment: Use WHERE and LIKE.  And make sure you use parameters rather than generating a string.

Comment: Asking how to select a row of information by using a dropdown selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get your $name from your form submission.  Then generate a SELECT statement to grab all the records that match it.

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['name']);

        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM `youTable` WHERE `name`=?');
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $name);
        $stmt->execute();
```

If you are choosing whether to search for a name, city, etc...  You need to update your code accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

This is all pretty basiic MySQL syntax.  Check out codeacademy.  Let's assume your database column names match the values within your `select` options.  A very basic search would look like this:

```
<form METHOD="POST"><? // need to use POST and close form also at the end. ?>
    <input type="text" name="search">
    <select NAME="searchtype">...</select><? // Important you name the select! ?>
        <option value="Name">Name</option>
        <option value="Address">Address</option>
        <option value="company_address">company_address</option>
        <option value="contact_number">contact_number</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
include "connect.php";
$type = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['searchtype']);
$search = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['search']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM propertydetail WHERE ".$type." LIKE '%".$search."%'";

?>
```

Comment: SQL injection.  Bad idea.  Combine this answer with mine.

Comment: Does the `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function not avoid injection?  Either way, was just trying to show the `WHERE` and `LIKE` syntax.  Still haven't worked much with the mysqli library yet.

Comment: It helps, but it's not foolproof.  Anyway, since this answer incorporated the things I left out, I suggested combining it with mine.

Comment: Roger that.  Thanks for the info.